# Properly display images with OpenGL if the image is loaded by Resource.rc file

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I have two choices. I can read my image `pinmap.jpg` from `Resource.rc` or read the image from `STBI_Image` library.

```
// Simple helper function to load an image into a OpenGL texture with common settings
inline bool ReadImageFromResource(GLuint* out_texture, int width, int height) {
    // Locate the resource in the application's executable.
    HRSRC imageResHandle = FindResource(
        NULL,             // This component.
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_IMAGE1),   // Resource name.
        L"Image");        // Resource type.
    HRESULT hr = (imageResHandle ? S_OK : E_FAIL);

    // Load the resource to the HGLOBAL.
    HGLOBAL imageResDataHandle = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        imageResDataHandle = LoadResource(NULL, imageResHandle);
        hr = (imageResDataHandle ? S_OK : E_FAIL);
    }

    // Lock the resource to retrieve memory pointer.
    LPVOID image_data = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        image_data = LockResource(imageResDataHandle);
        UnlockResource(imageResDataHandle);
        hr = (image_data ? S_OK : E_FAIL);
    }

    if (image_data == NULL)
        return false;

    // Create a OpenGL texture identifier
    GLuint image_texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &image_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image_texture);

    // Setup filtering parameters for display
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // This is required on WebGL for non power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // Same

    // Upload pixels into texture
#if defined(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH) && !defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
#endif
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
    *out_texture = image_texture;
    return true;
}
```

The results is:

[image]

When I read the image from STBI-library, then the image looks like this:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

// Simple helper function to load an image into a OpenGL texture with common settings
inline bool ReadImageFromSTBI(const char* filename, GLuint* out_texture, int* out_width, int* out_height)
{
    // Load from file
    int image_width = 0;
    int image_height = 0;
    unsigned char* image_data = stbi_load(filename, &image_width, &image_height, NULL, 4);
    if (image_data == NULL)
        return false;

    // Create a OpenGL texture identifier
    GLuint image_texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &image_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image_texture);

    // Setup filtering parameters for display
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // This is required on WebGL for non power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // Same

    // Upload pixels into texture
#if defined(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH) && !defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
#endif
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
    stbi_image_free(image_data);

    *out_texture = image_texture;
    *out_width = image_width;
    *out_height = image_height;

    return true;
}
```

You see the difference between the color and the image above is shifted due to the `C` to the left. It should be at the right side of the image. Notice that the image above is displayed with `GL_RBG` and this image is displayed with `GL_RGBA`. Else, I cannot display the image.

[image]

**Question:**

It seems to be different data depending on how I load the data of the image. I have looked at the data of the image. The variable `image_data` differes.

How do I properly display images with OpenGL if the image is loaded by Resource.rc file and not loaded by file such as STBI-library?

Comment: Based on the images alone it looks like there's an RGB <==> BGR mix up somewhere in the colour model being used.

Comment: @G.M Yes. But `GL_BGR` is removed from OpenGL.

Comment: @euraad huh? `GL_BGR` format is part of core as of OpenGL 4.6.

Comment: @YakovGalka really? I don't find that macro in my open gl. Im using ImGui.

Comment: @euraad It's not ImGui responsibility to expose OpenGL API. What OpenGL loading library do you use? Figure that out, and make sure that you're building against the right version of OpenGL.

Comment: @YakovGalka I'm using Vcpkg and using the latest OpenGL version of Vcpkg.

Comment: Do you have visual studio 2022? I can give you the project if you want to see it with your own eyes.

Comment: @euraad chances are you're using OpenGL 1.1 -- which is the default you get on Windows, and is **27 years** old. Vckpkg doesn't have "opengl" in it. You need a proper [OpenGL loader library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), and create a forward compatible context. This is all really basic stuff, so please grab a modern OpenGL tutorial and follow that. I definitely don't want to look at your project.

Comment: @YakovGalka I understand. Why so old version for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoadResource` does not decode, decompress, or interpret the resource data in any way. What you get in your `image_data` is a pointer to a memory block that contains exactly the contents of your `pinmap.jpg` file.

Interestingly, what you have is a **bitmap** rather than an actual JPEG file. If it wasn't, you'd get a bunch of noise instead of anything resembling your image. From what my crystal ball tells me, you imported that once-has-been JPEG into the resource editor with the "Add Resource > Import..." function of Visual Studio. When done this way, it converts the file to a bitmap, overwriting the original on disk. (Seriously, Microsoft, what were you smoking!?)

The results you observe thus can be explained:

- The horizontal wrap-around offset is due to the BITMAP file and info headers at the beginning of the resource.
- The colors are off because of the BGR <-> RGB mismatch.

**If you want to keep the resource as JPEG,** you can add it by manually editing the rc file, or by reverting the file after Visual Studio is done with messing it up. However, if you choose this route, you must decompress the JPEG (because OpenGL expects plain RGB data rather than JPEG). One way would be to call `stbi_load_from_memory` on that `image_data` you got from `LockResource`. Stbi will decompress the JPEG into RGB (in that order).

**If you want to keep working with the BITMAP resource,** then all you need is to skip the headers and flip the channels.

For skipping the headers you parse the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` that's located at `image_data`. The offset to the pixel data is in the `bfOffBits` field in the header:

```
actual_image_data = (char*)image_data + ((BITMAPFILEHEADER*)image_data)->bfOffBits;
```

For fixing the channel order you can pass `GL_BGR` for the `format` parameter (**not** the `internalformat`!!) of `glTexImage2D`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, actual_image_data);
```

Comment: I tried to load from memory resource `    unsigned char* image_data  = (unsigned char*) stbi_loadf_from_memory((const stbi_uc*)void_data, 700*810, &image_width, &image_height, NULL, 4);
` But it did not work out very well.

Comment: @euraad why `loadF`? you need it without 'f', or else you'll be getting floating point result where unsigned bytes are requested.

Comment: Thank you. Did not notice that little "f". Now it's working. I can see the half of the image, sort of. But the color is right! The reason why I cant see the complete imeage is because the `length` of the `void_data` is unknown. Do you know how to "measure" `void_data`?

Comment: Never mind. Found it! `DWORD size_of_void_data = SizeofResource(NULL, imageResHandle);`. Thank you. Now it's working for me.